# Another look at the trinomial of the form: $ax^n+bx+c=0$

Tags: soft-question, diophantine-equations

Has the trinomial of the form $ax^n+bx+c=0$ been fully studied for $n>2$? If so, please let me know of any reference or interesting findings. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to be fully studied? It seems you think the case $n=2$ has been fully studied, but there are still unanswered questions related to quadratic polynomials.

Comment: @KCd, so base on what you said, the answer must be no as far as you know.right?

Comment: I can't answer the question until you explain what it even means. That is why I asked why you did not include $n=2$. In what sense did you think $ax^2+bx+c$ has been fully studied?

Comment: I mean, is there a general method of finding the roots of these trinomials?

Comment: @KCd, the quadratic formula.

Comment: There are cubic and quartic formulas, easily found by a web search, but above degree $4$ there is nothing similar in general, even for the special trinomials in your question. But I think it is more important to point out that your view of what makes polynomials worthwhile is overly narrow. Just because you have a formula for the roots hardly makes such polynomials fully studied.

Comment: thanks for your input. Again,based on your comment, the answer is NO as far as you know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the equation,

$$ax^p+bx^q+c = 0\tag1$$

has been studied in detail and can be solved in terms of *hypergeometric functions* in one variable. To quote (eq.42) of this [Mathworld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html),

*"... This technique gives closed-form solutions in terms of hypergeometric functions in one variable for any polynomial equation which can be written in the form $x^p+bx^q+c = 0$..."*

**P.S.** If in *radicals*, there are special cases that can be so solved, such as the irreducible,

$$x^5-5x^2-3 = 0$$

$$x^6+3x+3 = 0$$

$$x^8-5x-5=0$$

There are an infinite number of solvable examples for $p=5$ and, if I remember correctly, for $p=6,8$ as well. However, none are known for $p=7$.

Comment: thank you. Please see my next post.